# PHP Empty 500 Error

Tags: php, html, syntax

I have this code to check if any input values are left empty, but for some reason the page keeps spitting out a 500 error ( and even with error reporting, it will only give me a 500 error ).

Here's my code

**PHP**

```
function checkInput() {
echo 'There are one or more errors with your application';
if (empty($_POST['MINGNAME'])) {
    die('Please fill in your in-game name<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MSTEAMID'])) {
    die('Please fill in your Steam-ID ( by signing in through Steam )<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MAGE'])) {
    die('Please fill in your age<br>')
} elseif (empty($_POST['MULX1'])) {
    die('Please fill out the first ULX command<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MULX2'])) {
    die('Please fill out the second ULX command<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MULX3'])) {
    die('Please fill out the third ULX command<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MULX4'])) {
    die('Please fill out the fourth ULX command<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MULX5'])) {
    die('Please fill out the fifth ULX command<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MSIT1'])) {
    die('Please fill out your first situational<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MSIT2'])) {
    die('Please fill out your second situational<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MSIT3'])) {
    die('Please fill out your third situational<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MSIT4'])) {
    die('Please fill out your fourth situational<br>');
} elseif (empty($_POST['MSIT5'])) {
    die('Please fill out your fifth situational<br>');
} else {
    echo '';
}
}
checkInput();
```

I have no idea what's wrong with my code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: look at the error log. Ubuntu it defaults to `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. To show the errors on page, in addition to turning on error reporting you would need to set `display_errors` to `1` as well.

Comment: This is really a debugging problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon on line 10:

```
} elseif (empty($_POST['MAGE'])) {
    die('Please fill in your age<br>') /* Here */
```

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid. Thank you so much for pointing that out lol.

Answer (score 0):

There's no semicolon after:

```
die('Please fill in your age<br>')
```

This would cause the PHP interpreter to send out a `500 Internal Server Error` if you don't have `display_errors` shown.

Comment: @burger97979 You are welcome. `:)`